# Is there a way to time babel code blocks?

Tags: org-babel

Is there a way to do something like the example below to time the execution of any babel code block ?

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :timeit
#+END_SRC
#+results 40s
results here

#+BEGIN_SRC python :timeit
#+END_SRC
#+results 40s
results here
```

Is there something built in or a new package that will give me this functionality.